# splitting up the views of my stripe subscription details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I have stripe subscriptions on my site. yesterday i created a basic way for the user to view their payment history and cards used. i now want to break this up into two views so that the payment history is on one page and the card(s) used is on another page. I feel like i must be missing something but when i tried to do this nothing is showing on the page. I am pretty new to rails so the whole stripe subscriptions thing has been a bit of a challenge but getting there. This is the original code could someone offer some guidance as to the steps i need to follow. I tried literally splitting this into two different view file but that didn't work so i have gone back to where i was originally now!

subcriptions/show.html.erb

```
<h1>View your payment history and cards</h1>

<h4><%= @charges.data.length %> Charges! </h4>
<% @charges.data.each do |charge| %>
     <%= charge.statement_description %>
    £<%= charge.amount %>
    <%= Time.at(charge.created).strftime("%d/%m/%y") %>
<% end %>


<h4><%= @charges.data.length %> Cards! </h4>
<% @cards.each do |card| %>
    <%= card.brand %>
    **** **** **** <%= card.last4 %>
    <%= card.exp_month %>/<%= card.exp_year %>
<% end %>
```

subscriptions controller:

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @subscription = Subscription.new
  end

 def create
  # raise 'a'
  @subscription = Subscription.new(params[:subscription].permit(:stripe_card_token))
  @subscription.user = current_user
  if @subscription.save_with_payment(params[:plan]) #(current_user)
    redirect_to @subscription, :notice => "Thank you for subscribing!"
  else
    render :new
  end
end

  def destroy
  end

  def show
    customer_token = current_user.subscription.try(:stripe_customer_token)
    @charges = customer_token ? Stripe::Charge.all(customer: customer_token) : []
    @cards =  customer_token ? Stripe::Customer.retrieve(customer_token).cards : []
  end


end
```

subscriptions model

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user_id #it should be always compulsary
  # attr_accessible :plan

  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

  def save_with_payment(plan)
    if valid?
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: 'subscription', plan: plan, card: stripe_card_token)
      self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
      save!
    end
  rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
    logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
    errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
    false
  end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way to achieve it, is to create 2 methods in controller (for example `payments` and `cards`):

```
def payments
  customer_token = current_user.subscription.try(:stripe_customer_token)
  @charges = customer_token ? Stripe::Charge.all(customer: customer_token) : []
end

def cards
  customer_token = current_user.subscription.try(:stripe_customer_token)
  @cards =  customer_token ? Stripe::Customer.retrieve(customer_token).cards : []
end
```

create 2 views for these (`payments.html.erb` and `cards.html.erb` under `/views/subscriptions/` directory):

payments.html.erb:

```
<h1>View your payment history</h1>
<h4><%= @charges.data.length %> Charges! </h4>
<% @charges.data.each do |charge| %>
     <%= charge.statement_description %>
    £<%= charge.amount %>
    <%= Time.at(charge.created).strftime("%d/%m/%y") %>
<% end %>
```

cards.html.erb:

```
<h1>View your cards</h1>
<h4><%= @charges.data.length %> Cards! </h4>
<% @cards.each do |card| %>
    <%= card.brand %>
    **** **** **** <%= card.last4 %>
    <%= card.exp_month %>/<%= card.exp_year %>
<% end %>
```

and edit routes by:

```
resources :subscriptions do
  get '/payments', to: 'subscriptions#payments' # or get 'subscriptions/payments', to: 'subscriptions#payments' (depending on which link you would like to see)
  get '/cards', to: 'subscriptions#cards'
end
```

This would be pretty much it. Run `rake routes` to see generated routes to use it correctly and you're good to go. Please check for spelling mistakes in case you'll copy something - not sure if I didn't make any.

Comment: could you possibly clarify if i had the following routes initially how i should amend them to take onboard the above

Comment: resources :subscriptions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy, :show]

Comment: hey! sorry for late response, been really busy yesterday. It will work within your resource definition, so any modifications needed